# Java Generics: Stream toArray()

Tags: java, generics, stream, toarray

Given a simple generic class:

```
private static class Container<T> {
    private List<T> aList;
    private T aValue;

    private Container(List<T> aList, T aValue) {
        this.aList = aList;
        this.aValue = aValue;
    }
}
```

Initialize a list of that class:

```
List<Container<?>> container = new ArrayList<>();
// Add some elements...
```

Not possible (The method toArray(IntFunction<A[]>) in the type Stream<List<capture#1-of ?>> is not applicable for the arguments (List<?>[])):

```
container.stream().map(value -> value.aList).toArray(new List<?>[0]);
```

Possible:

```
container.stream().map(value -> value.aList).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new List<?>[0]);
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Stream`'s `toArray` takes a `IntFunction<A[]>` - i.e. a function that accepts an `int` and returns an array.

You tried to pass an array to it.

It should be used as follows:

```
container.stream().map(value -> value.aList).toArray(List<?>[]::new)
```